# Is there a difference in the string object created by out-string and toString()?

Tags: json, powershell

I'm parsing some text from a json file and based on the text I want to do things to the text.

```
foreach ($jsonText in $jsonFile.row[0]){ 

$stringA = $jsonText.ToString()
$stringB = $jsonText| Out-String

switch ($stringA)
{
    'A' {'do things'}
    'B' {'do other things'}
    'C' {'do somethings'}
}
```

The string from piping out-string does not produce a string that would work in the switch case, so I am wondering if there is a difference with these two strings?

Comment: Yes, there is a difference. Refer to the `Out-String` documentation. Especially when dealing with complex objects, `ToString` will generally return the *type name* (i.e. `System.Collections.Hashtable`). In your specific case, you can attach a debugger and look at the values and see what the difference is.

Answer (score 3):

- The *fundamental* difference is that [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string) uses PowerShell's rich for-display output-formatting system for non-string, non-primitive objects, whereas `.ToString()` simply delegates the stringification to the .NET type at hand (which, unless overridden by a type, simply reports the full *type name*).

  - In other words: **`Out-String` by default creates a single, multi-line string with the same richly formatted, for-the-human-observer representation you would see in the console.**
  - Adding `-Stream` sends this representation *line by line* through the pipeline (resulting in an *array* of lines if captured in a variable). Given that representations of complex objects are multi-line and in tabular form share a header, a single line does *not* correspond to a single input object.
- As of PowerShell 7.2, **an unfortunate aspect of `Out-String` (without `-Stream`) is that it *appends a trailing newline*** to whatever the output-formatting system reports, and that also applies to *strings* as input, which PowerShell's formatting system otherwise represents as-is; similarly, .NET primitive types and a few single-value-only types are represented by their `.ToString()` return values.

  - [GitHub issue #14444](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14444) discusses this problematic behavior.

```sh
# Unfortunately, these equivalences are true.
# With a single input object, adding -Stream would avoid the trailing newline.

('foo'.ToString() + [Environment]::NewLine) -eq ('foo' | Out-String)

((42).ToString() + [Environment]::NewLine) -eq (42 | Out-String)
```

---

### Uses of `Out-String`

- Use it if you explicitly want a string representation of the rich, for-display representation that PowerShell's formatting system produces.

  - Combined with `-Stream`, this can serve as a quick-and-dirty way to search through the display output of a command via [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string); PowerShell even comes with function, `oss`, that wraps `Output-String -Stream`, so that you can do something like:

    ```sh
    # Quick-and-dirty search through the formatted representations 
    # of all defined drives, without having to worry about property names.
    Get-PSDrive | oss | Select-String \\server1
    ```
  - Regrettably, `Select-String` doesn't search through the formatted representations *by default* (in which case you could omit the `oss` call), even though that would make sense (it actually searches through the typically useless `.ToString()` representations).

    - [GitHub issue #10726](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10726#issuecomment-567628146) proposes changing the default behavior.
- With *external programs*, you can use it to join their output lines - which PowerShell invariably interprets as *text* (strings) - into a single-multiline string.

  - E.g, to get the output from `tzutil /l` as a single, multi-line string:

    ```sh
    $output = tzutil /l | Out-String
    ```
  - Unfortunately, this is again hampered by the unexpected addition of a trailing newline, as discussed in [GitHub issue #14444](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14444); workarounds:
  - Trim the trailing newline, in the simplest case with `.Trim()`

    ```sh
      $output = (tzutil /l | Out-String).Trim()
    ```
  - Use a `-join` operation instead:

    ```sh
      $output = (tzutil /l) -join [Environment]::NewLine
    ```